# On your opinion what is the meaning of this quote?

Tags: meaning, quotes, quotations

> Mental Health is not a destination but a process. It's about how you drive, not where you're going." *Noam Shpancer.*

Comment: Maybe a quick example to explain the figurative usage: It's about how you drive (live your life), not where you're going (death, as it is the inescapable end of the journey of life). In other words, the focus is on the ongoing process, not the result that you get at the end.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mental Health is not a destination but a process- We don't keep ourselves mentally healthy to achieve something in the longer run. Being mentally healthy is for the moment! Once the moment is gone it no longer matters whether you were healthy before or might be after.

the latter part emphasizes-
That now is important not what comes after.

In other words- If you don't drive properly then are you going to reach somewhere?

It's to say that be mentally healthy NOW for NOW.
You cant say I will be mentally healthy now so that I will be better tomorrow.
Also, one can't say I will be mentally healthy tomorrow for tomorrow. It starts now!